# Can a condition for duplicate elements in a column be efficiently phrased in SQL?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I'm working with a query, in which I join two tables and then aim to only remain with rows of particular interest. One such condition is that only rows which have duplicate values in particular columns are selected.

The data and value are arbitrary for this case. Team1 and Team2 contain team name values such as 'Team Red', 'Team Blue',... and so on

```
SELECT date, team1, team2, value

FROM database.team_table

INNER JOIN database.teaminfo_table ON database.team_table

WHERE 

       date >= sysdate  --example condition

AND

       --condition to only take in the specified rows
```

I'm doubtful if this is an efficient way of going about what I want to do. I wonder what's the correct way to express this condition and also if there's a better way of implementing it.

The expected result is that if, lets say for the column Team A, if there are two entries called 'Team Red', and no more such duplicates in the column. The final result should be two rows, each with the Team A value being Team Red.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Are you referring to a logical `intersection`? It isn't quite clear what you are asking based on your wording. Are you referring to the `JOIN` output, or the `WHERE` clause filtering your output?

Comment: I'm referring to the WHERE clause filtering the output, sorry if I'm not clear, my SQL is quite shaky at the moment

Comment: so you only want to return rows where the same combination of values exists more than once in the table?

Comment: specifically if there are repeated values in one column, say in `team1` there are two rows with `Team Red`, we want all the rows with such values

Answer (score 2):

WHERE clauses are evaluated for each individual row.

If the criterion for retaining the row in the result set is the existence of another row in the same table that satisfies some characteristics, then the WHERE clause to use is

`WHERE EXISTS ...`

So you'll get

`SELECT ... FROM TEAM_TABLE AS OUTER WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TEAM_TABLE INNER WHERE INNER.whatever < / = / > OUTER.whatever
)`

Remember to also include the necessary WHERE clause in that inner SELECT to make sure that only rows that are ***different*** from the OUTER row will satisfy the condition.

e.g.

`AND OUTER.<primary key here> <> INNER.<primary key here>`

or

`AND OUTER.ROWID() <> INNER.ROWID()`

if you're on a DBMS that has these ROWID() things (and will then usually perform slightly better if you use it).

Comment: Thanks! I will check the `Where exists` condition and your suggestion